# Error with loadmat in scipy: could not read bytes

Tags: python, scipy

I had a problem with a project where I'm trying to use the loadmat function but get the above error:

```
File "project.py", line 107, in load_data
    return loadmat(filename, appendmat=False)['data'].squeeze()
File "/home/xx/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 136, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
File "/home/xx/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 292, in get_variables
    res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
File "/home/xx/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 252, in read_var_array
return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:7119)
File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 703, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:6244)
File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 776, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_real_complex (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:7572)
File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 448, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_numeric (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:4323)
File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 353, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_element (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:3913)
File "scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx", line 92, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.GenericStream.read_string (scipy/io/matlab/streams.c:2182)
File "scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx", line 79, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.GenericStream.read_into (scipy/io/matlab/streams.c:1977)
OSError: could not read bytes
```

I had import:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
```

Comment: What's the .mat file version?  Newer MATLAB uses HDF5 rather than it's own binary form.  `loadmat` only works on the older version.  `h5py` is needed load new versions.

Comment: The type of the files are binary.
I'd save the files in the same program with savemat

Comment: Looking more at the error, it is evident that it got quite a ways into reading the file.  Anything unusual in the data that was saved?  Does the save/load sequence work for other files or data?  Is it just this file, or the current pairing of save/load functions?

Comment: Oh yes, it was an error at the moment of saved the data. Thanks